# Signing certificate is invalid

Tags: xcode

I am not able to automatically validate signing certificates with XCode 9. I have tried everything including cleaning my project using cmd+shift+k. and removing all ld signing certificates. I have a paid developer account and it is still not working.

[image]

Comment: Try to create new certificates and provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Add the apple account to the xcode using preferences. [image]

And this should help you.